# Find li element by its child element id in jQuery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a list of li elements (without any ids) generated dynamically and they are embedded into the html page as follows ;

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="selected"><a id="item1">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item2">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item3">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item4">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item5">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item6">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
    <li><a id="item7">LOREM IPSUM</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Is this possible to access and change class of the li of a specific "a" element by its "a" tag id ?

Briefly I am out after the following;

- get element by id = item7.  Then access its li and change its class as "selected"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var li = $('#item7').closest('li');
li.addClass('selected');
```

Just to clear things out:

[jQuery.closest(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) will look for the closest parent matching the selector.

[jQuery.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) will return all parents of the element. If you pass a selector as argument, it will only return the parents that match the selector.

[jQuery.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) will return the direct parent of the element. If you pass a selector as argument, it will only return the parent if it matches the selector.

[jQuery.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) will return the direct child nodes of the element. If you pass a selector as argument, it will only return the children that match the selector.

[jQuery.find(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will return all child nodes in all levels matching the selector.